# angular js: ng-min \ ng-max

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I using angular js, combined with angular ui, to show modal window in my website.
**HTML**

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
    <div class="modal-header text-center">
        <h3 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">Jump to page</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body text-center" id="modal-body">
        <input type="number" ng-model="info.page" class="text-center" ng-enter="ok()" ng-min="{{info.min}}" ng-max="{{info.max}}" />
        <div>MAX: {{info.max}}</div>
        <div>MIN: {{info.min}}</div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()" style="margin-top: 20px;">OK</button>
    </div>
</script>
```

The user have to fill an input number in a range of `info.max` to `info.min`.

Here the relevant angular code - Triggering the modal window opening:

```
function gotoPageDialog(fileNo, current, max) {
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
        controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
        size: 'sm',
        resolve: {
            current_info: function() {
                return {
                    fileNo: fileNo,
                    page: current,
                    max: max,
                    min: 1
                }
            }
        }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function(result) {
            //...
        };
    }
}
```

And the modal window it self:

```
app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function($scope, $uibModalInstance, current_info) {
    $scope.info = current_info;

    $scope.ok = function() {
        $uibModalInstance.close($scope.info);
    };

    $scope.cancel = function() {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
});
```

The result is:

[image]

The input value is "-1", What's mean that the `ng-min` and `ng-max` range is not working.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: I didn't think ng-min/ng-max applied HTML5 validation? Check your `$form` object and I would imagine that it returns `$form.$valid` as false.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Change `ng-min` and `ng-max` to

```
min="{{info.min}}"
max="{{info.max}}"
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your `ng-min` and `ng-max` sintax to

`ng-min="{{info.min}}"`

`ng-max="{{info.max}}"`

Comment: You are right. I changed it. But, this wasn't solve the problem. Same behavior.

Comment: Have you tried to insert *manually* the values of ng-max and ng-min? for example : ng-max="2". See if this way works: in that case, we'll know thats a problem of your variables and not of the directive.

Comment: Manual values wasn't solve the problem. Same behavior. I found that using this `min="{{info.min}}" max="{{info.max}}"` is solving the problem. Thank you!

Comment: For me using min="{{hard_coded_value}}" doesn't work. like min="{{40}}". I'm using angular 1

Comment: Are you using a `<input type="number"` ? 
Keep in mind you should also use the angular directive `ng-min` and `ng-max`.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following syntax:

```html
<input type="number" ng-min="minQuantity" ng-max="maxQuantity">
```

Where minQuantity and maxQuantity are properties on the $scope